How to pass a concrete instance to a generic class with bounded wildcard?
TLDR;
Why I cannot pass an implementation of an interface to a bounded wildcard initialised class to generically handle multiple payloads?
Full question
Let's imagine you have to handle some JSON-payloads with a common wrapper structure around only differs in some attributes of a known structure.
Something like:
{
 "id": "object-one",
 "timestamp": "...",
 "payloadType": "ConcreteClassA",
 "payload": {
    "classAProperty": "barfoo"
  }
}

{
 "id": "object-one",
 "timestamp": "...",
 "payloadType": "ConcreteClassB",
 "payload": {
    "classBProperty": 42
  }
}

If I now have a generic function or class which should handle both concrete types i used bounded wildcard to say that it's only about to handle implementation of this interface.
How do I pass an instance of a concrete class to that function?
What am I missing here?
interface CommonInterface { }

class ConcreteClassA implements CommonInterface {
  String classAProperty;
}
class ConcreteClassB implements CommonInterface {
  int classBProperty;
}

class Wrapper <WrappedType extends CommonInterface>{
    void doSomethingWithWrappedType(WrappedType wrappedObject) {
        // do something with wrappedObject
    }
}

class Example {
    void doSomeThingWrapped() {
        Wrapper<? extends CommonInterface> wrapper = new Wrapper<>();
        wrapper.doSomethingWithWrappedType(new ConcreteClassA()); // <-- Error here Required: capture of ? extends CommonInterface, Provided: ConcreteClassA
    }
}


Well, the issue is that Wrapper<? extends CommonInterface> basically says it could be Wrapper<CommonInterface> or Wrapper<ConcreteClassB> etc., i.e. all the compiler knows is that wrapper deals with types that have CommonInterface interface as an upper bound but could be more concrete than that.
Now imagine what would happen if wrapper were a Wrapper<ConcreteClassB> and you'd try to call wrapper.doSomethingWithWrappedType(new ConcreteClassA()); - that should break, shouldn't it? And since the compiler can't rule out this could be the case those types of calls aren't allowed.
To make it more formal, this is called PECS (Producer Extends, Consumer Super):

A method "producing" (or returning) something could use <? extends A> to tell the compiler that everything returned has at least the type A and all its provided properties, methods etc.
A method "consuming" (or taking as a parameter) something could use <? super A> to tell the compiler that whenever you pass some instance of type A or any of its super classes that's going to be ok. The compiler basically knows that the parameter will satisfy the boundaries of the generic type.

So let's apply this to your example:
If you'd use doSomethingWithWrappedType(<? extends CommonInterface> wrappedObject) (which is what your test code comes down to) then all the compiler would know that wrappedObject will at least have the type CommonInterface and the method couldn't use anything more specific from the implementations. That's ok but in this case you could as well use doSomethingWithWrappedType(CommonInterface wrappedObject).
On the other hand, if you want the compiler to tell you that you can't pass instances of ConcreteClassA to a wrapper that deals with ConcreteClassB then using <? extends CommonInterface> is not the way to do this (the wildcard would make it more lenient again). In this case just use Wrapper<ConcreteClassB>.

Hello @Thomas,
thanks for the detailed explanation.
... all the compiler knows is that wrapper deals with types that have CommonInterface interface as an upper bound but could be more concrete than that.
With this being said that means that a Wrapper<CommonInterface> should be able to handle ConcreteClassA-instances since there are at least some kind of CommonInterface?

@PeterC.Glade yes, Wrapper<CommonInterface> should be able to handle anything that implements CommonInterface as that's the contract you're defining. If all you care about is the fact that CommonInterface is implemented there's no need for a wildcard.

In fact, for the code as given, there’s not even a need for Generics. The class could be declared as class Wrapper { void doSomethingWithWrappedType(CommonInterface wrappedObject) { /* do something with wrappedObject */ } } and that’s it.
